# How can add custom validation in zip code field at checkout Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, validation

I have tried with all solution. Actually, i want to `add number validation`means anyone will not able to write characters in text-field.

when I see in the browser by inspect element then getting this code.

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
value: value,
valueUpdate: 'keyup',
hasFocus: focused,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}" name="postcode" placeholder="" aria-describedby="notice-HGXM9L3" id="HGXM9L3">
```

if we can also add any custom class then we can set validation by jquery. anyone have an idea for that, please.

Comment: Have you checked below my answer for the issue?

Comment: Yes i have checked with your code, but still allow to enter character.  i have copied layout file form /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/fontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml to /app/design/frontend/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am sharing code for add custom validation to postcode field

`checkout_index_index.xml` file code for **postcode** field.

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

You need to add below code for number validation

```
<item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
```

Final postcode field code

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**Note:** You have to override `checkout_index_index.xml` in your theme.

Comment: Yes i have checked with your code, but still allow to enter character. i have copied layout file form /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/fontend/layout/checkout‌​_index_index.xml to /app/design/frontend/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/

Comment: check it with core file. I think your file is not properly override.

Comment: which core files? can show path or more guide please.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: I checked by core files, it show your code it show validation message when anyone enter text. but i want user can not write text means user will be not allow to write text, if user write any then he can write only number in zipcode field.

Comment: You can applied only number validation not restrict any character. You have to write your custom code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i want same for address book in customer account. can you please share you idea for that

Comment: Customer address book form is render with php code not by knockout so you can add validation class directly in phtml file. for Ex. edit address code render from vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml. So you can override this file in your theme and apply validation class in postcode field.

Answer (score 0):

Default magento 2 doesn't provide validation like anyone will not able to write characters in text-field. So you should go with custom jquery or HTML 5.

Please check below URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Hope above solution work for you.